# Google Chrome Extension default in a new tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension

so I am trying to make a google chrome extension and I want it to open when you open a new tab. Kind of like muz.li. Basically, when you press ctrl+t to open a new tab instead of showing google, it shows my extension.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple add the code below to open the extension when a new tab is opened, you don't need a background js or html file. It is in the manifest.json file:

```
"chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "page.html"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use the chrome.tabs.onCreated event to detect when someone opens up a new tab.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onCreated